# How can I access a variable set in Parallel ForEach outside the loop in C#?

Tags: c#, timer, parallel.foreach

`RunQuestion` is a method that uses a `Parallel.ForEach` loop to append the characters read to a `StringBuilder` variable (`builder`). The parallel loop is wrapped in a timer that fires every 10 seconds so that I can look at the content of the builder variable to find out how much of the data has been processed. The issue is the builder passed to DisplayOutput is always blank whenever the timer triggers.
I am looking for a way to get the parallel for loop to update the builder object passed to DisplayOutput.

```
    public Task RunQuestion(ICharacterReader[] readers, IOutputResult output)
    {
        var wordsFrequency = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var objLock = new object();

        try
        {
            var reportPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            using (new Timer(_ => DisplayOutput(builder), null, reportPeriod, reportPeriod))
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(readers, reader =>
                {
                    var stream = ReadStream(reader);
                    lock (objLock)
                        {
                            builder.Append(stream);
                        }
                });
            }

            wordsFrequency = GetWordsFrequency(builder);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private void DisplayOutput(StringBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var item in GetWordsFrequency(builder))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Key} - {item.Key}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `ReadStream` and what is it returning?

Comment: Are you saying you cannot access builder?

Comment: Because it works when I try it https://dotnetfiddle.net/7XWeYH

Comment: What does the GetWordsFrequency do? Maybe you are missing a ToString somewhere?

Comment: Hi @DaveyvanTilburg your code example is perfect. Now imagine your parallel foreach loop will take about 60 seconds to complete. How can you display the contents of the "sb" string builder variable (in your code) every ten seconds while the loop is doing its stuff?

What I tried to do in my code is wrap the parallel foreach loop inside a timer that triggers every 10 seconds but the issue is the string builder variable passed to the timer nerver gets populated. It looks like the timer portion of the code does not have access to the builder variable being updated inside the foreach loop.

Comment: @CodeStranger, all the ReadStream does is read and return a StringBuilder object containing the characters read.

Comment: @Benajax You'll have to create a different thread apart from the parallel.foreach that moniters the StringBuilder and reports status.

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg, that was helpful. I have now figured that out. Thanks.

Comment: @Benajax No problem, I'm trying to gain some rep ^^ hope you do not mind ill add it as an answer too and that you set it as accepted answer? Will also help clean up the queue where people look for unanswered questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to create a different thread apart from the parallel.foreach that moniters the StringBuilder and reports status.